# ServiceNow REST POST create WorkNote format text

Tags: json, unicode, servicenow

Setting my Request Body

```
request.setRequestBody("{\"work_notes\":\"After the Comma,\\\\nNew line\"}");
```

I try to create a work note while creating an Incident. So far this works but I have problems formatting my text. For example in this case, after the Comma I want to have a new line. Using \n seems not to work.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
    var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
    request.setEndpoint('https://my-instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident');
    request.setHttpMethod('POST');    

    var user = 'admin';
    var password = 'admin';

    request.setBasicAuth(user,password);
    request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    request.setRequestBody("{\"work_notes\":\"After the Comma,\\\\nNew line\"}");
    var response = request.execute();
    gs.log(response.getBody());
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solved it using

[code] Text
 more text[/code]

as syntax.